# Trying to use a JSON API that isn't technically an API

Tags: php, json, api

I just started playing D&D, and I'm working on a project for my group to help us play the game a littler easier. We all created Characters on D&D Beyond. They don't have an official API, but apparently, if you type in "your-character-sheet/**json**" - you can get some JSON output about your character.

I attempted to grab this data in php as I normally would

```
<?php
  $request = "https://www.dndbeyond.com/profile/PixiiBomb/characters/9150025/json";
  $url = file_get_contents($request);
  $json = json_decode($url, true);
  echo $json["character"]["id"];
?>
```

This **should** echo out: "9150025" - but I actually see nothing. It's totally blank. So I tried to `echo $url`, and this is what I see.
[image]
Which of course, it not what I should be seeing (because that is formatting from their website, minus the stylesheets)

I went back to the JSON view and manually saved the data as **pixii.json** This time using the following:

```
$request = "uploads/dndbeyond_sheets/pixii.json"; // Saved to my harddrive
$url = file_get_contents($request);
$json = json_decode($url, true);
echo $json["character"]["id"];
```

**THIS WORKS** if I manually save the file. But that would mean that every time we level up, I would have to manually save all of our JSON data, and run some code to read it and update it.

Is there something else I can try to allow me to use this URL instead of having to manually save the page?

Ideally, I would like to have all of my code written , and then when we level up, I press a button and grab the new data from the site (**which I don't need help with, that's not part of the question**). Instead of manually visiting each website, saving the data, and then parsing it.

Comment: You're going to have to relay some sort of authentication token.  Honestly, the easiest way to do this would be to make a browser extension.  It can piggy back off of your existing authentication tokens and dump out the files you need.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Brad - I'm not sure how I would go about doing that. Is there something already made you can recommend?

Comment: Browser extensions are actually pretty easy to get started in!  There is a good tutorial for Chrome extensions provided by Google that I'd recommend looking at.  From there, it's just a little JavaScript to get the files you need.  Take a look at the Fetch API.  It's functionally equivalent to the way you're using `file_get_contents()` here.

Comment: ok I will look into it

Comment: Learning how to use the `cURL` library in PHP to run the login process along with saving the cookies needed to pass that information back to the JSON page would seem to me to be easier than writing a browser extension. But then, I have written several such things, and never a browser extension, so it might just be a case of seeing this as a nail because that's my hammer.